# multiline boolean expression in haskell

Tags: syntax, purescript

I have a function `findEntryByAddress` which has an inline declararation of `filterEntry`. I would like to add another boolean check, but then there would be too many chars in one line.

How can I split the boolean expression, one equals check per line.

```
findEntryByAddress :: Address -> AddressBook -> Maybe Entry
findEntryByAddress = head <<< filter filterEntry
  where
  filterEntry :: Entry -> Boolean
  filterEntry entry = entry.firstName == firstName && entry.lastName == lastName
```

I have checked [Haskell's Indentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation) guide, nothing on multiline expressions.
code from [purescript-book](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read).

Comment: Is this Haskell or Purescript (it's tagged as both but the question title says 'haskell')? If Haskell, just put it on a new line and indent it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, you want to do something like this?

```
findEntryByAddress :: Address -> AddressBook -> Maybe Entry
findEntryByAddress = head <<< filter filterEntry
  where
  filterEntry :: Entry -> Boolean
  filterEntry entry = entry.firstName == firstName && 
                      entry.lastName == lastName &&
                      entry.age == age
```

In a where, you can jump a line but you have to put the rest of the expression one space after the beginning of the definition otherwise Haskell will think you're defining something new. So this is correct:

```
where f = x &&
       y
```

But this isn't:

```
where f = x &&
 y
```

By the way, in Haskell, there is no `Boolean` type, the type of `True` and `False` is `Bool`.